# Rails nested resources within a namespace

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes, activeresource

I have this in my view:

```
form_for [:support, @thread, @reply], url: support_thread_replies_path do |f|
```

And this in my `routes.rb`:

```
namespace :support do
  resources :threads do
    resources :replies
  end
end
```

That doesn't work:

> ### Routing Error
>
> No route matches `{:action=>"new", :controller=>"support/replies"}`

If I remove the `url:` key from my `form_for`, I just get a `NoMethodError` when the form helper tries to call an undefined path helper method:

I get the same Routing Error even when I remove the `:support` symbol from the beginning of the array in my sample view code (using `:support` was suggested by an answer to another similar question here)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pass an instance of `Thread` as the first parameter in the path helper:

```
support_thread_replies_path(@thread)
```

That way Rails knows what thread you're creating a new reply for.

I believe you should be able to do this without the `:url` key or the path helper at all, though.

Comment: By the way, I get caught by this all the time. `rake routes` can be really helpful with these kind of things.